# The frequency of DatetimeIndex is missing after groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range('20140301',periods=6)
id_col = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
data_col = np.random.randn(6,4)
data = np.concatenate((id_col.T, data_col), axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=list('IABCD'))
print df

print "before groupby:"
for index in df.index:
    if not index.freq:
        print "key:%f, no freq:%s" % (key, index)

print "after groupby:"
gb = df.groupby('I')
for key, group in gb:
    #group = group.resample('1D', how='first')
    for index in group.index:
        if not index.freq:
            print "key:%f, no freq:%s" % (key, index)
```

The output:

```
            I         A         B         C         D
2014-03-01  0  0.129348  1.466361 -0.372673  0.045254
2014-03-02  1  0.395884  1.001859 -0.892950  0.480944
2014-03-03  2 -0.226405  0.663029  0.355675 -0.274865
2014-03-04  0  0.634661  0.535560  1.027162  1.637099
2014-03-05  1 -0.453149 -0.479408 -1.329372 -0.574017
2014-03-06  2  0.603972  0.754232  0.692185 -1.267217

[6 rows x 5 columns]
before groupby:
after groupby:
key:0.000000, no freq:2014-03-01 00:00:00
key:0.000000, no freq:2014-03-04 00:00:00
key:1.000000, no freq:2014-03-02 00:00:00
key:1.000000, no freq:2014-03-05 00:00:00
key:2.000000, no freq:2014-03-03 00:00:00
key:2.000000, no freq:2014-03-06 00:00:00
```

But after I uncomment the statement:

```
#group = group.resample('1D', how='first')
```

It seems no problem. The thing is, when I running on a large dataset with some operations on the timestamp, there is always an error "cannot add integral value to timestamp without offset". Is it a bug, or did I miss some thing?

Answer (score 0):

You are treating a groupby object as a DataFrame.

It is *like* a dataframe, but requires `apply` to generate a new structure (either reduced or an actual DataFrame).

The idiom is:

```
df.groupby(....).apply(some_function)
```

Doing something like: `df.groupby(...).sum()` is syntactic sugar for using `apply`. Functions which are naturally applicable to using this kind of sugar are enabled; otherwise they will raise an error.

In particular you are accessing a `group.index` which *can* be but is not guaranteed to be a `DatetimeIndex` (when time grouping). The `freq` attributes of a datetimeindex are inferred when required (via `inferred_freq`).

You code is very confusing, you are `grouping`, then `resampling`; `resample` does this for you, so you don't need the former step at all.

`resample` is de-facto equivalent of a groupby-apply (but has special handling for the time-domain).